# Keras LSTM - Many to many with embedding layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I am training a LSTM to predict event occurences. For each day I have a vector like [1,0,1] to denote that the first and third event occured, whereas the second one did not.

I want to extend this problem to work for multiple people, where each person has a distinct `agent_id`. This means that somehow I need to present my model with the `agent_id` as a feature. Although I'm not sure if this is the best way, I made the first entry of my vector the `agent_id`, so it looks like for example [123456, 1, 0 ,1].

Now what the LSTM model does is for each event output a probability of it occuring on the next day. So how I see the input/output would be: [agent_id, did event 1 occur today?, did event 2 occur today? did event 3 occur today?] -> LSTM -> [probability of event 1 occuring tomorrow, probability of event 2 occuring tomorrow, probability of event 3 occuring tomorrow]

Now the input has a longer length than the output. As far as I understood, from the answer to this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305863/how-to-train-lstm-model-on-multiple-time-series-data , I need to have an embedding layer that can change the size of my input so that the LSTM gives me the desired output.

For this, I tried to do the following:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *
xin = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, window_length), dtype='int32')
xemb = Embedding(x_traindict[123456].shape[2], x_traindict[123456].shape[2]-1)(xin) #from what I give in to what I want to get out # 3dim (batch,time,feat)
seq = LSTM(x_traindict[123456].shape[2]-1, return_sequences=True)(xemb)
mlp = TimeDistributed(Dense(y_traindict[123456].shape[1], activation='softmax'))(seq)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=xin, outputs=mlp)
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
print(f"batch size is {batch_size}, window_length = {window_length}, x_train.shape is {x_traindict[123456].shape} and y_train.shape is  {y_traindictalt[123456].shape}")
model.summary()
model.fit(x_traindict[123456], y_traindict[123456], epochs=20)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
batch size is 358, window_length = 7, x_train.shape is (358, 7, 149) and y_train.shape is  (358, 148)
Model: "model_7"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_12 (InputLayer)       [(358, 7)]                0         
                                                                 
 embedding_14 (Embedding)    (358, 7, 148)             22052     
                                                                 
 lstm_16 (LSTM)              (358, 7, 148)             175824    
                                                                 
 time_distributed_11 (TimeDi  (358, 7, 149)            22201     
 stributed)                                                      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 220,077
Trainable params: 220,077
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

My idea was that the Embedding would take the input from x_train, including the `agent_id` , and would learn to encode it to an input of the size of y_train, which does not include the `agent_id`. The LSTM will then learn to deal with what it receives from the embedding to correctly predict y_train. However, the code above gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "model_7" (type Functional).
    
    Input 0 of layer "lstm_16" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 7, 149, 148)
```

I do not understand this error.

What I would thus like to ask is:

1. Does my idea even make sense? By implementing the `agent_id` directly with the events, can the LSTM learn the time series prediction for different agents?
2. How can I fix the error in my code? If it helps, I basically filled in the template from the first answer to this post: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2654

**EDIT:**

1. I have tried changing xin to `xin = Input(batch_shape=(window_length,), dtype='int32')` but now get a
   Value error in the line where I say seq = ...:  `Input 0 of layer "lstm_26" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (7, 133).`
2. I also tried changing xin to `xin = Input(batch_shape=(window_length,number_of_transactions+1), dtype='int32')` but this produces `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_11" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 134), found shape=(None, 7, 134)`

Note: I had to take a new sample today. The 134 replaces the 149 events from above

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, I think the idea is valid. By placing the agent-id as the first element in the sequence the RNN will encode this information in the state which is subsequently used to predict the probabilities for an event. One thing to watch out for is that the model will try to generate a prediction given just the first sequence element - the agent-id.
2. I think your issue is that you included the batch size in the input call, but batch size is implied and doesn't need to be defined, so
   `xin = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, window_length), dtype='int32')` 
   should become `xin = Input(batch_shape=(window_length), dtype='int32')`

Comment: Thank you for your help. However for 2) changing xin like this (I had to add an extra comma behind window_length, because otherwise it gave an error that batch_shape was an integer) returns the following error: Input 0 of layer "lstm_26" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (7, 133). This error occurs in the line where I define seq = ... I will add a clearer explanation to my original post

Comment: Ah, when excluding the batch size we'd also need to rename the argument from `batch_shape=` to `shape=`. So you could try `Input(shape=(window_length,), dtype='int32')`.